# can't install SSL certificate in IIs 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis-7

I tried to install SSL certificate in IIS 7  server (windows server 2008). installation of intermediate certificate in windows mmc console was a success, but when I tried to install the certificate in IIS through server certificates, installation becomes success, but after a refresh installed certificate just vanishes.tried with re keyed certificates and that was also not successful. as I don't have privatekeys.txt file provided, I was not able to create .pfx files.please help me to sort out this issue.let me know why SSL certificates vanishes in IIS 7 server?

Comment: If you don't have the private key, what are you expecting installing the certificate to do?!

Comment: Where is the private key exactly? You can't install a `.crt` file or `.p7b` file unless the private key is already installed.

Comment: dear @David, when i downloaded certificate from certificate issuing  website, i got only domain.crt file and an intermediate cert(.p7b).i had done installing certificate as explained in [this](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4801/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-7) blog and it got worked in one of my server, issue is with my second server. any idea about why this happens with IIS 7 server? do you think this happened because of  a configuration issue with IIS server?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install a certificate on a machine unless the corresponding private key is already installed. Even if you could, what would the point be? A certificate binds a key to an identity. Without the key, the certificate is useless. (The certificate is public. The key is private.)

Likely the server it worked on has the private key already, possibly because the private key was generated on that machine. The instructions in the support blog you link assume the private key is already installed on the machine.

You need to export the private key from the machine that generated the CSR. Then you can import that private key on other machines so that they can use the certificate to identify themselves.

Answer (score 0):

mmc is not very user friendly with the snap in module etc. If you going to do operations like exporting and reimporting certs on IIS like David suggested you may want to look at other more user friendly tools like [SSLTools Manager](http://www.ssltools.com/manager)